# Python 3.x while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

so here is the  idea of the exercise:

I have to make this code:

```
count = int(input())
while count>0:
    print (count)
    count = count - 1
```

Sum up the numbers from count, meaning:

```
5 5
4 9
3 12
2 14
1 15
```

I've done that part, but I have a problem with the next one.

```
3 3
2 7
1 8
```

My code is the following:

```
count = int(input())
sum = count
while count>0:
    print("%d %d"%(count, sum))
    count = count - 1
    sum = sum + count
```

I don't understand how to go from 2 to 7 and from 1 to 8.

Thank you in advance, and I am really sorry for the stupid topic name but I don't really know how to phrase the problem.

Comment: If it is an assignment it should tell you where the `3 7 8` comes from.

Comment: Are you sure the expected output is 3 7 8? It would make more sense if it was 3 5 6. Double check what the exercise is wanting

Comment: the input I get out is 3 5 6 and the exercise wants an output of 3 7 8

Comment: @morskiq123 if the exercise does not say WHY it wants 3 7 8 you could hardcode printing these numbers just as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems some kind of exercise in finding a pattern matching a given series without the rule-of-creation given

Comment: It wants to get those numbers through an input of 3 @timgeb

Comment: @morskiq123 why? What's the rule?

Comment: No rule, but I can't hard-code because it checks 3 diffrent inputs: 5, 0 and 3. 5 and 0 run perfectly but 3 I can't understand why it's not working. I've been trying to do it with a `for` / `while` loop within an `if` command in the whole `while` loop

Comment: @morskiq123 then the exercise has an error, either in having a typo or being unclear. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will not work as is.

You need to read in each number, not just one, you need sum each number (and not sum the value twice, and not decrement the count, which was being used originally just to loop a number of times.

Assuming that an input of 0 means to stop, and without any error checking:

```
count = int(input())
sum = 0
while count>0:
  sum = sum + count
  print (count, sum)

  # next input
  count = int(input())
```

Comment: this just puts me in an infinite loop without the `count = count -1`.  And it still doesn't work since it goes 
3 3 
2 5
1 7

Comment: It will not infinite lop as it reads a new count each iteration of the loop (marked #next input)  However we need to know the calculation required as the 1st example if just a sum, the 2nd one is not - is it supposed to be the same algorithm or a another one for the 2nd example.